# Why can't I consume MyContext in App Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ContextProvider, MyContext } from "./Context/MyContext";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const value = useContext(MyContext);
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <div className="App">{value}</div>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

### If I want to consume the useContext exactly on App Component. I get the value as undefined on App Component but the value of all other component is okay. So, I want to know what is the mechanism behind it. Why I can't access to useContext in App component.

Comment: You need to access the context in a *nested* component. Something that is a **child** of the provider. Here you're doing it inside `App`, which is the direct parent of the provider. You'd have to  wrap the `App` in the `ContextProvider` in order to access the context inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ContextProvider provides the values within your Context to all it's child components. The value you are supplying to your <div> comes from the parent component of ContextProvider in your case, ie the App. At this point your Provider has still not been set up, you have to wrap App inside provider to access the values of the context. In other words the Provider needs to be the Parent of app to provide it values and not the other way around